# Mejor camino para bajar la resolución a una imagen

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que ejecuto algoritmos pesados sobre una fotografía. El usuario usa su celular para tomar una fotografía, entonces la foto es dinámica. luego de esto uso un plugin para que el usuario recorte su cara en un cuadrado. Esto queda a un tamaño de 280px x 280px, y se genera una nueva imagen de este tamaño .

No sé mucho del tema pero me dicen que debo de bajar la resolución de la imagen para optimizar los tiempos de ejecución del algoritmo, ya que en un celular el procedimiento que necesito se demora un poco más.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Necesito tener una imagen de 280px x 280 px, pero sin perder la calidad ni pixelar. Necesito optimizarla.

Comment: se que no es de mucha ayuda pero busca en google de alguna libreria que te de una funcion que haga el trabajo, yo te recomiendo del jquery(base64), no reinventes la rueda.

Comment: pero si hago eso, el pedazo que se crea al recortar la imagen tendrá la misma calidad..asi se convierta a base64

Comment: En una imagen digital la resolución y lo que llamas tamaño son lo mismo, si quieres que la imagen ocupe menos tendrás que perder calidad

Comment: Puedes usar canvas. A diferencia de ti, yo buscaba reducir el peso de la imagen antes de enviarla al servidor, pero es sumamente complicado, y las pocas API's que existen son gratuitas pero hasta cierto punto. En todo los días que estuve investigando resulta que usar canvasl, para ti, puede ser tu mejor opción.